# JDBC - Calling PLSQL from JAVA gives Java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I'm in a huge trouble with my call to a PLSQL from Java.
Here's my code:

```
static final String PLSQL = "{call DBK_PDG_METADATI_CEDOLINO.dbp_main(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";

Connection conn = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource());
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(PLSQL);

    for (Cedolino item : items) {
        LOG.info("################# ELABORAZIONE CEDOLINO " + item.getTestata().getAnagrafica().getCodFiscaleAmministrato() + " #################");
        cedolini.getCedolino().add(item);
        setParametersForPlSql(cs, item);

        try{
            cs.execute();
        }catch(SQLException e){
            LOG.info(e.toString());
        }

    }

cs.close();
conn.close();

private void setParametersForPlSql(CallableStatement cs, Cedolino ced){

    try {
        cs.setInt("tipo_lancio", 1);
        cs.setString("iscr", ced.getTestata().getTrattamento().getIscrizione().trim());
        cs.setString("rts", ced.getTestata().getDpt().trim());
        cs.setString("codfisc", ced.getTestata().getAnagrafica().getCodFiscaleAmministrato().trim());
        cs.setString("lingua", this.lingua);
        cs.setString("file_name", null);
        cs.setString("dir_spec", null);
        cs.setString("stato_elab", "S");
        cs.setString("descr_elab", null);


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This code works good except for `cs.execute`, that gives me this error

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DBP_MAIN'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I checked a thousand times, parameters and types and numbers match perfectly. DB connection is also good, because I do some caching first and it works.

Already tried to delete `DBK_PDG_METADATI_CEDOLINO` but nothing it is needed.
Can you help me to figure out it?

Comment: If you use positional placeholders (`?`), you should use index-based setters (although I'm not 100% sure if Oracle may allow named any way in that case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Problem could be related to the JDBC driver which may not support Named Parameters.

Try to check it first like:

```
  Connection myConn = . . .   // connection to the RDBMS for Database
  DatabaseMetaData dbmd = myConn.getMetaData();
  if (dbmd.supportsNamedParameters() == true)
  {
      System.out.println("NAMED PARAMETERS FOR CALLABLE"
                        + "STATEMENTS IS SUPPORTED");
  }
```

and if it is not - use parameter indexes to set instead of names...

2. Is there any OUT or INOUT parameters in that Stored Procedure?

If so, you need to register those parameters using `registerOutParameter` of the `CallableStatement` and give a placeholder for output.

Comment: Sorry for late answer! I tried your solution using parameters indexes and.. it works!
The reason could be that first I used ojbdc14 as jar and named parameters were ok, then after a downgrade to ojdbc5 were not anymore.
Thank you man!